# What is issue occurred with Fabric?

Tags: google-fabric

Fabric dashboard show loading on my app. it occurred to me today. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgabZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. This was likely due to a production issue [earlier](http://status.fabric.io/incidents/vx8kv2n2j8d6). Try refreshing your dashboard to see if it loads.

Comment: @Mike Bonnell I am experiencing this issue today and no reports of service interruption has been reported. The dashboard is working fine, however crashlytics is down and loads infinitely

Comment: Hey Grease - this was due to a different production issue: http://status.fabric.io/incidents/2rcnh263skmx I would recommend looking at http://status.fabric.io before posting on SO with this type of issue.

Comment: @MikeBonnell We have a strange thing going on that started on sep 7th where Craslytics started to report hundereds and sometimes over 1 thousand of crashes a day. All the same crash and we have been investigating this and we have no way to reproduce it. Apart from that, we have no users reporting any crash. Could this somehow be related to your production issue? Any other reprts from people experiencing the same?

Comment: Haven't heard other reports of this and wouldn't be related to our production issue.